# How to check the existence of a Windows service in a batch file

Tags: windows-services, batch-file

How can I check the existence of a Windows service in a batch file?

The user is inputting a service name, and I want to check that the service does exist before continuing with my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>NET START | FIND "Workstation"
```

where "Workstation" is the name of the service

Comment: I'm doing something like the user inputs the service name. But before I continue with my script. I want to make sure that the service he entered is valid. I don't want to start the service ....

Comment: then you replace "Workstation" with parameter and save the result of this command in a variable. Then check if it's empty

Comment: Careful when whatever you're looking for might appear *within* the name of another service.

Comment: how do I store the result into a variable? Sorry I'm not a batch file guru.

Comment: Ok I found it with For /F "Tokens=2" %%I in ('<any command>') Do Set <variable name>=%%I

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

color 1F



SET KEYS=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ACPI

for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('REG QUERY "%KEYS%" ^| find "Start"') do set START=%%i

IF "%START%" == "%START%" ECHO %START% | find /I "%START%" && IF "%START%" NEQ "0x3" REG ADD %KEYS% /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f >> %COMPUTERNAME%_MODIFIER.TXT

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO %KEYS% >> %COMPUTERNAME%_SERVICE_MISSING.TXT
```

OR

```
@echo off
color 1F


@sc query >%COMPUTERNAME%_START.TXT

ECHO REPORT MISSING INSTALL SERVICES >%COMPUTERNAME%.TXT


find /I "AcPrfMgrSvc" %COMPUTERNAME%_START.TXT >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 NET START "AcPrfMgrSvc"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO AcPrfMgrSvc >>%COMPUTERNAME%.TXT
```

Comment: repeating my comment to your last post (last chance): _edit and format your code_

Comment: still not formatted ;-) to find out how-to, click on the question mark to show the formatting menu, then on "code" to read the instruction. Alternatively, select all the code lines, then ctrl-k (works only if no tabs in the code)